# replace string but not a specific word that contains that string

Tags: php

suppose I have a string

```
$string = 'this is my gal_s, not my 1_s not 2_s not 3_s';
$find = '_s';
$replace = '';
```

I woul like to return

```
"this is my gal_s, not my 1 not 2 not 3"
```

so the word `gal_s` is not affected

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, if you are able to define the rules of replacement. For example, do you only want to replace the string if it comes after a number, or only if it is _not_ after `gal` ?

Comment: to replace everything  that has _s except gal_s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use preg_replace with negative lookbehind like this:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<!\bgal)_s/', '', $str);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/GeTsv3

Answer (score 0):

@anubhva answar is good also alternate try

```
$string = 'this is my gal_s, not my 1_s not 2_s not 3_s';
$find = '_s';
$replace = '';
$arr = explode(',', $string);
$arr[1] = str_replace('_s', '', $arr[1]);
echo $string = implode($arr);
```